# Calculate the number of conenected pixels of a particular value in Numpy/OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, numpy-ndarray

```
def get_area(center_x: int, center_y: int, mask: np.ndarray) -> int:
    if mask[center_x][center_y] != 255:
        return -1
    return ...
```

Now I got this function above that takes in a value for the x and y and finds the number of pixels that are connected to this pixel with the value of 255.

Now let's say, I have a simple np.ndarray that looks like this:

```
[
    [255,255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,255,255],
    [255,  0,  0,255,255,255,  0,  0,255],
    [  0,  0,255,  0,  0,  0,255,  0,  0],
    [  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0],
    [  0,255,  0,255,255,255,  0,255,  0],
    [  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0],
    [  0,  0,255,  0,  0,  0,255,  0,  0],
    [255,  0,  0,255,255,255,  0,  0,255],
    [255,255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,255,255]
]
```

If I took the center pixel of 255 as an input, the output of the function I am trying to build will be 5, since there are 4 neighboring pixels that are 255s.

I am amenable to using both `opencv` and `numpy`, but `np` is more preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def get_area(center_x: int, center_y: int, mask: np.ndarray) -> int:
    """
    Basic flood-fill area calculation on the mask using Breadth First Search
    """

    area = 0
    moves = [(1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (1, -1)]

    if mask[center_x][center_y] != 255:
        return -1

    visited = [[False for _ in range(mask.shape[0])] for _ in range(mask.shape[1])]
    q = deque()
    q.append((center_x, center_y))
    visited[center_x][center_y] = True

    while q:
        x, y = q.popleft()
        for move in moves:
            if (x + move[0] >= mask.shape[0] or y + move[1] >= mask.shape[1] or
                    x + move[0] < 0 or y + move[1] < 0):
                continue
            if mask[x + move[0]][y + move[1]] == 255 and not visited[x + move[0]][y + move[1]]:
                area += 1
                q.append((x + move[0], y + move[1]))
                visited[x + move[0]][y + move[1]] = True

    return area
```

Decided to code an answer by myself and made a breadth first search floodfill algorithm on the supplied mask.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

imgMtx = [
    [255,255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,255,255],
    [255,  0,  0,255,255,255,  0,  0,255],
    [  0,  0,255,  0,  0,  0,255,  0,  0],
    [  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0],
    [  0,255,  0,255,255,255,  0,255,  0],
    [  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0,  0,255,  0],
    [  0,  0,255,  0,  0,  0,255,  0,  0],
    [255,  0,  0,255,255,255,  0,  0,255],
    [255,255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,255,255]
]

img = Image.fromarray(np.asarray(imgMtx))

blobs = np.asarray(img) > 125
labels, nlabels = ndimage.label(blobs)

unique, counts = np.unique(labels, return_counts=True)
```

Comment: Can we do this without scipy?

Comment: and PIL? I think importing such heavyweight libraries for a BFS + numpy task is a bit of an overkill.